# Export data from MongoDB with MongoExport and query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to get a data which doesn't start with "0". This `query` works inside of `MongoDB` command line

```js
db.Hikanshou.find({"number":/^(?!0)/})
```

but when I do this with `mongoexport` as

```
mongoexport --host MYIP --port 27017 --username "MYUSERNAME" --password "MYPASS" --authenticationDatabase "admin" --db TotsugoDataDB --collection Hikanshou --query '{"number": /^(?!0)/}' --out data.json
```

I'm getting an error

```
Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input. Position: 17. Character: /
```

And with like this `{"number": "/^(?!0)/"}` it wont match... How could I parse that `/^(?!0)/`?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
mongoexport --host MYIP --port 27017 --username "MYUSERNAME" --password "MYPASS" --authenticationDatabase "admin" --db TotsugoDataDB --collection Hikanshou -q '{"number": {"$regularExpression":{"pattern":"^(?!0)", "options":""}}}' --out data.json
```

From the docs for mongoexport:

> The query must be in Extended JSON v2 format (either relaxed or canonical/strict mode), including enclosing the field names and operators in quotes:

Basically, you need extended JSON v2, not v1.

Take a look at [JSON v2 guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).

Answer (score 0):

I could successfully export data using the same regex query from Windows command prompt and MongoDB v4.2:

```
mongoexport --db=testdb --collection=testcoll --query="{ \"number\": { \"$regex\": \"^(?!0)\" } }" --out=testoutput.json
```

Comment: I'm trying this in ubuntu and bash says: "-bash: !0: event not found".

Comment: Try this: `--query='{ "number": { "$regex": "^(?!0)" } }'`

Comment: I am afraid I dont have access to linux environment to check what works correctly.