# MongoExport: Can you query a field?

Tags: json, database, mongodb, mongoexport

I am currently working on a solution using Mongo database.
We must use MongoExport for this one.
Is there a way to enhance my MongoExport command to include a filter on the fields?

For instance:
`-q:"{"Status": "COMPLETE"}"`
`-f:Id,EanCode,Channels:{"$elemMatch":{"ChannelId":"Test"}`

Update:
Hello again, by suggestion in the comments I am adding am example document.

Document:

```
{
  "Id": "1"
  "Status": "COMPLETE",
  "EanCode": "1234567890",
  "Barcode": "100100100",
  "Name": "Test Product",
  "Channels": [
    {
      "ChannelId": "Test"
    },
    {
      "ChannelId": "Dumbeldore"
    }
  ]
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "Id": "1"
      "Status": "COMPLETE",
      "EanCode": "1234567890",
      "Channels": [
        {
          "ChannelId": "Test"
        }
      ]
}
```

I can use any tool you suggest, might space out from the MongoExport.
But the important thing is that It must be optimized and export JSON Objects.

Thank you for your attention and help :)

Comment: Good practice is to add example document and  expected output ...

Comment: You can specify a query with a filter, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64885824/export-data-from-mongodb-with-mongoexport-and-query

Comment: @R2D2 Hello, as you suggested I added an example document and output. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I see you attempted  adding the option "--fields" ?  ( --fields=<field1[,field2]>, -f=<field1[,field2]> )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1.**
I think you cannot do with mongoexport directly , but you can do via aggregation:

```
 echo 'db.test.aggregate([{$match:{Status:"COMPLETE","Channels.ChannelId":"Test"} },{$addFields:{Channels:{ $filter: { input: "$Channels", as: "ch", cond: {$eq:["$$ch.ChannelId","Test"] }  } }} } ])' | mongo --authenticationDatabase admin  --port 27017 -u test -p xxxx --quiet > out.json
```

[playground1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zmw-oQkb1j7)

**Option 2:**
You output from aggregation to a output collection via $out and then you mongoexport.

[playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i1qskdwUQAZ)